# Does FileInputStream.skip() do a seek?

Tags: java, inputstream, seek, random-access

I want to copy the last 10MB of a possibly large file into another file.  Ideally I would use FileInputStream, skip() and then read().  However I'm unsure if the performance of skip() will be bad.  Is skip() typically implemented using a file seek underneath or does it actually read and discard data?

I know about RandomAccessFile but I'm interested in whether I could use FileInputStream in place of that (RandomAccessFile is annoying as the API is non-standard).

Comment: I just forgot if I tested this on oracle JVM or android, but FileInputStream.skip() checks for negative values.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depends on your JVM, but here's the source for `FileInputStream.skip()` for a recent openjdk:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
Java_java_io_FileInputStream_skip(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jlong toSkip) {
    jlong cur = jlong_zero;
    jlong end = jlong_zero;
    FD fd = GET_FD(this, fis_fd);
    if (fd == -1) {
        JNU_ThrowIOException (env, "Stream Closed");
        return 0;
    }
    if ((cur = IO_Lseek(fd, (jlong)0, (jint)SEEK_CUR)) == -1) {
        JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "Seek error");
    } else if ((end = IO_Lseek(fd, toSkip, (jint)SEEK_CUR)) == -1) {
        JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "Seek error");
    }
    return (end - cur);
}
```

Looks like it's doing a `seek()`.  However, I don't see why `RandomAccessFile` is non-standard.  It's part of the `java.io` package and has been since 1.0.

Comment: Thanks.  When I say RandomAccessFile is non standard it isn't nor does it provide a way of getting an InputStream that utility libraries typically expect.  Probably just the nature of what an RAF is.

Comment: My problem is after call skip() i use filechannel from fis.getChannel() to get charsequence to be applied to regex. Unfortunately the filechannel just restore back the skipped input

Comment: The problem with this is that we have to rely on that particular implementation to deduce the fact that it does a seek since AFAIK the information is not part of the interface/documentation. That is not a good idea. But maybe "discarding the skipped bytes" as it is stated means seeking over them to the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

you will be interested with this [LINK](http://www.coderanch.com/t/276838/java-io/java/seek-skipBytes)

it say that seek is faster than skip